# How to convert a map to a map kotlin

Tags: kotlin, java-stream

How can I convert a `Map<String, ArrayList<Int>>` to a `Map<String, Int>`?

My objects are as follows:

```
val mapOfItems = mapOf("x" to listOf(1, 2), "y" to listOf(1, 3), "z" to listOf(2, 3))
```

I want to get an object like this:

```
val mapOfSummedItems = mapOf("x" to 3, "y" to 4, "z" to 5)
```

I tried:

```
mapOfItems.map { (key, value) -> SummedItems(key, value.sum()) }
                .groupBy { it.key }

data class SummedItems(val key: String, val sum: Int)
```

That does not give me what I want that gives me an `Map<String, ArrayList<SummedItems>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.map()` on a `Map` generates a `List`.  While you can make this a `List<Pair>` and then use `associate*` operators to get back into a `Map`, you can also just map the values directly:

```
mapOfItems.mapValues { it.value.sum() }
```